# What tool should I use to capture video from a WebVR session?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I want to record myself using WebVR.

What tool should I use to capture video from a WebVR session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/).

You can record a portion of your screen or the entire monitor, it can handle compositing video from webcam and taking audio sources from the computer + mic. commonly used in like twitch streaming